# Decryption pad block corrupted

Tags: java, exception, encryption

```
    blocktoDo = new byte[block];
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file_dpt);
    fis = new FileInputStream(file_ct);     

    Cipher.getInstance(algorithm, "BC"); // Initiate the cipher in decrypt mode
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key); // Run decryption in single mode

    totalT = (long) 0; 
    while (fis.available() > 0) {
        fis.read(blocktoDo);
        startT = System.nanoTime();
        byte[] decryBytes = cipher.doFinal(blocktoDo);
        endT = System.nanoTime();
        fos.write(decryBytes);
        totalT += (endT - startT);
    }
    fis.close();
    fos.close();
```

I am encrypting and decrypting files of different sizes. While also having a rough time estimating on how long the actual encryption and decryption process took.

I am getting a pad block corrupted error here on the `doFinal` line.

What am I missing/doing totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on `available()` to detect the end of the stream. It may work now (for files), but it may not in the future. Instead, use the output of `read()`.

More importantly however you are calling `cipher.doFinal()`. One of the features of `doFinal()` is that it checks the padding for ciphers that require it (CBC and ECB mostly). Now padding is only applied at the end of the plaintext message, so if you try to unpad in the middle, your software implementation will fail.

Solutions:

- use `CipherInputStream`;
- use `update()` methods followed by `doFinal()` (over zero bytes), concatenating the resuls of the updates and `doFinal()` calls

And follow some tutorials about streams in Java.